# Composer and PDO on xampp windows 10

Tags: xampp, composer-php, windows-10

when i try to install composer it says:

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

in my php.ini file the extensions lines for php_pdo and php_pdo_mysql are UNcommented and the extension_dir is correct (absolute path for the ext folder) i checked the folder and i saw that php_pdo.dll was missing and i've installed it but the problem was not fixed....so any idea how to fix it?
thanks

Comment: Is there any real problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

my problem was solved...just updated xampp and tried to install composer again and it worked!